# Origin of mythical creatures

Tags: history

Where does Judaism believe the other gods originate from? If Hashem is the only G.od where did everyone get their notion of a deity from?

For example the ancient Egyptians had half-human and half-animal deities, same with the Greeks with centaurs. Where did these mythical creatures come from? Is there any basis to their [those gods] existence or is it complete hogwash?

I am not Chas vsholom suggesting that they are deities, my question is whether they [the half-human half-animal or other mythical creatures] are based on anything other than someone's imagination.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Foreign_Worship_and_Customs_of_the_Nations.1?lang=bi

Comment: One gemara [suggests](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Avodah_Zarah.43a.5?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi) that the Greco-Egyptian god Serapis is based on Yosef.

Answer (score 1):

According to Rabbi Ariel bar Tzadok, in his book The Greatest Story never told, the other “gods” are the Watchers mentioned in Daniel and Genesis 6.

Comment: Is there a chapter or paragraph in the book you can quote?